# Interpolation in Marching Square Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, interpolation, marching-cubes

[Here](https://github.com/mns-csharp/MarchingSquare) is the GitRepository of the source code.

- [Marching Square](http://jamie-wong.com/2014/08/19/metaballs-and-marching-squares/)

In the "Linear Interpolation" section This article discusses how to interpolate the values when the lines are oblique.

For example, for Case#2 it has the following calculation:

[image]

[image]

I have implemented the interpolation as follows:

```
public class Square
{
    public Point A { get; set; }//bottom left point
    public Point B { get; set; }//bottom right point
    public Point C { get; set; }//top right point
    public Point D { get; set; }//top left point

    public double A_data { get; set; }//bottom left data
    public double B_data { get; set; }//bottom right data
    public double C_data { get; set; }//top roght data
    public double D_data { get; set; }//top left data

    public Square()
    {
        A = new Point();
        B = new Point();
        C = new Point();
        D = new Point();
    }

    private double GetCaseId(double threshold)
    {
        int caseId = 0;

        if (A_data >= threshold)
        {
            caseId |= 1;
        }
        if (B_data >= threshold)
        {
            caseId |= 2;
        }
        if (C_data >= threshold)
        {
            caseId |= 4;
        }
        if (D_data >= threshold)
        {
            caseId |= 8;
        }

        return caseId;
    }

    public List<Line> GetLines(double Threshold)
    {
        List<Line> linesList = new List<Line>();

        double caseId = GetCaseId(Threshold);

        if (caseId == 0) {/*do nothing*/ }
        if (caseId == 15) {/*do nothing*/ }

        if ((caseId == 1) || (caseId == 14))
        {
            double pX = B.X + (A.X - B.X) * ((1 - B_data) / (A_data - B_data));
            double pY = B.Y;
            Point p = new Point(pX, pY);

            double qX = D.X;
            double qY = D.Y + (A.Y - D.Y) * ((1 - D_data) / (A_data - D_data));
            Point q = new Point(qX, qY);

            Line line = new Line(p, q);

            linesList.Add(line);
        }
        /*2==13*/
        if ((caseId == 2) || (caseId == 13))//B
        {
            double pX = A.X + (B.X - A.X) * ((1 - A_data) / (B_data - A_data));
            double pY = A.Y;
            Point p = new Point(pX, pY);

            double qX = C.X;
            double qY = C.Y + (B.Y - C.Y) * ((1 - C_data) / (B_data - C_data));
            Point q = new Point(qX, qY);

            Line line = new Line(p, q);

            linesList.Add(line);
        }
        /*3==12*/
        if ((caseId == 3) || (caseId == 12))
        {
            double pX = A.X;
            double pY = A.Y + (D.Y - A.Y) * ((1 - A_data) / (D_data - A_data));
            Point p = new Point(pX, pY);

            double qX = C.X;
            double qY = C.Y + (B.Y - C.Y) * ((1 - C_data) / (B_data - C_data));
            Point q = new Point(qX, qY);

            Line line = new Line(p, q);

            linesList.Add(line);
        }
        /*4==11*/
        if ((caseId == 4) || (caseId == 11))
        {
            double pX = D.X + (C.X - D.X) * ((1 - D_data) / (C_data - D_data));
            double pY = D.Y;
            Point p = new Point(pX, pY);

            double qX = B.X;
            double qY = B.Y + (C.Y - B.Y) * ((1 - B_data) / (C_data - B_data));
            Point q = new Point(qX, qY);

            Line line = new Line(p, q);

            linesList.Add(line);
        }
        /*6==9*/
        if ((caseId == 6) || (caseId == 9))
        {
            double pX = A.X + (B.X - A.X) * ((1 - A_data) / (B_data - A_data));
            double pY = A.Y;
            Point p = new Point(pX, pY);

            double qX = C.X + (D.X - C.X) * ((1 - C_data) / (D_data - C_data));
            double qY = C.Y;
            Point q = new Point(qX, qY);

            Line line = new Line(p, q);

            linesList.Add(line);
        }

        /*7==8*/
        if ((caseId == 7) || (caseId == 8))
        {
            double pX = C.X + (D.X - C.X) * ((1 - C_data) / (D_data - C_data));
            double pY = C.Y;
            Point p = new Point(pX, pY);

            double qX = A.X;
            double qY = A.Y + (D.Y - A.Y) * ((1 - A_data) / (D_data - A_data));
            Point q = new Point(qX, qY);

            Line line = new Line(p, q);

            linesList.Add(line);
        }

        /*ambiguous case*/
        if (caseId == 5)
        {
            double pX1 = A.X + (B.X - A.X) * ((1 - A_data) / (B_data - A_data));
            double pY1 = A.Y;
            Point p1 = new Point(pX1, pY1);
            double qX1 = C.X;
            double qY1 = C.Y + (B.Y - C.Y) * ((1 - C_data) / (B_data - C_data));
            Point q1 = new Point(qX1, qY1);
            Line line1 = new Line(p1, q1);

            double pX2 = C.X + (D.X - C.X) * ((1 - C_data) / (D_data - C_data));
            double pY2 = C.Y;
            Point p2 = new Point(pX2, pY2);
            double qX2 = A.X;
            double qY2 = A.Y + (D.Y - A.Y) * ((1 - A_data) / (D_data - A_data));
            Point q2 = new Point(qX2, qY2);
            Line line2 = new Line(p2, q2);

            linesList.Add(line1);
            linesList.Add(line2);
        }
        if (caseId == 10)
        {
            double pX1 = B.X + (A.X - B.X) * ((1 - B_data) / (A_data - B_data));
            double pY1 = B.Y;
            Point p1 = new Point(pX1, pY1);
            double qX1 = D.X;
            double qY1 = D.Y + (A.Y - D.Y) * ((1 - D_data) / (A_data - D_data));
            Point q1 = new Point(qX1, qY1);
            Line line1 = new Line(p1, q1);

            double pX2 = D.X + (C.X - D.X) * ((1 - D_data) / (C_data - D_data));
            double pY2 = D.Y;
            Point p2 = new Point(pX2, pY2);
            double qX2 = B.X;
            double qY2 = B.Y + (C.Y - B.Y) * ((1 - B_data) / (C_data - B_data));
            Point q2 = new Point(qX2, qY2);
            Line line2 = new Line(p2, q2);

            linesList.Add(line1);
            linesList.Add(line2);
        }

        return linesList;
    }
```

But, this is not working properly.

Can anyone check the Interpolation part and tell me what went wrong?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71102/interpolation-on-marching-cubes-algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your repo, and the error is not in the code you posted :|

Actual error is in how you initialize your data in MarchingSquare.cs

Replace the following:

```
double a = Data[j + 1, i];
double b = Data[j + 1, i + 1];
double c = Data[j, i + 1];
double d = Data[j, i];

Point A = new Point(xVector[i], yVector[j + 1]);//A
Point B = new Point(xVector[i + 1], yVector[j + 1]);//B
Point C = new Point(xVector[i + 1], yVector[j]);//C
Point D = new Point(xVector[i], yVector[j]);//D
```

with:

```
double a = Data[j, i];
double b = Data[j, i + 1];
double c = Data[j+1, i + 1];
double d = Data[j+1, i];

Point A = new Point(j, i);//A
Point B = new Point(j, i+1);//B
Point C = new Point(j+1, i+1);//C
Point D = new Point(j+1,i);//D
```

and you will get the desired result (maybe it is transposed).

Edit: i think I got it transposed: [Plot[Sin[x/100.0] * Cos[y/100.0]] = 0.9, x = 0 to 250, y = 0 to 500](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BSin%5Bx%2F100.0%5D+*+Cos%5By%2F100.0%5D%5D+%3D+0.9%2C+x+%3D+0+to+250%2C+y+%3D+0+to+500)

Having looked a bit at the interpolation code:

- use enum for cases instead of cryptic constants
- do not cast caseId to double
- extract interpolation to helper methods!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace G__Marching_Sqaure
{
    public class Square
    {
        public Point A { get; set; } //bottom left point
        public Point B { get; set; } //bottom right point
        public Point C { get; set; } //top right point
        public Point D { get; set; } //top left point

        public double A_data { get; set; } //bottom left data
        public double B_data { get; set; } //bottom right data
        public double C_data { get; set; } //top roght data
        public double D_data { get; set; } //top left data

        public Square()
        {
            A = new Point();
            B = new Point();
            C = new Point();
            D = new Point();
        }

        private LineShapes GetCaseId(double threshold)
        {
            int caseId = 0;

            if (A_data >= threshold)
            {
                caseId |= 1;
            }

            if (B_data >= threshold)
            {
                caseId |= 2;
            }

            if (C_data >= threshold)
            {
                caseId |= 4;
            }

            if (D_data >= threshold)
            {
                caseId |= 8;
            }

            return (LineShapes)caseId;
        }

        public List<Line> GetLines(double Threshold)
        {
            List<Line> linesList = new List<Line>();

            LineShapes caseId = GetCaseId(Threshold);

            if (caseId == LineShapes.Empty)
            {
                /*do nothing*/
            }

            if (caseId == LineShapes.All)
            {
                /*do nothing*/
            }

            if ((caseId == LineShapes.BottomLeft) || (caseId == LineShapes.AllButButtomLeft))
            {
                var p = InterpolateHorizonal(B, A, B_data, A_data);
                var q = InterpolateVertical(D, A, D_data, A_data);
                Line line = new Line(p, q);
                linesList.Add(line);
            }

            /*2==13*/
            if ((caseId == LineShapes.BottomRight) || (caseId == LineShapes.AllButButtomRight)) //B
            {
                var p = InterpolateHorizonal(A, B, A_data, B_data);
                var q = InterpolateVertical(C, B, C_data, B_data);
                Line line = new Line(p, q);

                linesList.Add(line);
            }

            /*3==12*/
            if ((caseId == LineShapes.Bottom) || (caseId == LineShapes.Top))
            {
                // interpolate vertical
                var p = InterpolateVertical(A, D, A_data, D_data);
                var q = InterpolateVertical(C, B, C_data, B_data);
                Line line = new Line(p, q);
                linesList.Add(line);
            }

            /*4==11*/
            if ((caseId == LineShapes.TopRight) || (caseId == LineShapes.AllButTopRight))
            {
                var p = InterpolateHorizonal(D, C, D_data, C_data);
                var q = InterpolateVertical(B, C, B_data, C_data);
                Line line = new Line(p, q);
                linesList.Add(line);
            }

            /*6==9*/
            if ((caseId == LineShapes.Right) || (caseId == LineShapes.Left))
            {
                var p = InterpolateHorizonal(A, B, A_data, B_data);
                var q = InterpolateHorizonal(C, D, C_data, D_data);
                Line line = new Line(p, q);

                linesList.Add(line);
            }

            /*7==8*/
            if ((caseId == LineShapes.AllButTopLeft) || (caseId == LineShapes.TopLeft))
            {
                var p = InterpolateHorizonal(C, D, C_data, D_data);
                var q = InterpolateVertical(A, D, A_data, D_data);
                Line line = new Line(p, q);
                linesList.Add(line);
            }

            /*ambiguous case*/
            if (caseId == LineShapes.TopRightBottomLeft)
            {
                var p1 = InterpolateHorizonal(A, B, A_data, B_data);
                var q1 = InterpolateVertical(C, B, C_data, B_data);
                Line line1 = new Line(p1, q1);

                var p2 = InterpolateHorizonal(C, D, C_data, D_data);
                var q2 = InterpolateVertical(A, D, A_data, D_data);
                Line line2 = new Line(p2, q2);

                linesList.Add(line1);
                linesList.Add(line2);
            }

            if (caseId == LineShapes.TopLeftBottomRight)
            {
                var p1 = InterpolateHorizonal(B, A, B_data, A_data);
                var q1 = InterpolateVertical(D, A, D_data, A_data);
                Line line1 = new Line(p1, q1);

                var p2 = InterpolateHorizonal(D, C, D_data, C_data);
                var q2 = InterpolateVertical(B, C, B_data, C_data);
                Line line2 = new Line(p2, q2);

                linesList.Add(line1);
                linesList.Add(line2);
            }

            return linesList;
        }

        private static Point InterpolateVertical(Point point, Point point1, double data, double data1)
        {
            double qX = point.X;
            double qY = point.Y + (point1.Y - point.Y) * ((1 - data) / (data1 - data));
            Point q = new Point(qX, qY);
            return q;
        }


        private static Point InterpolateHorizonal(Point start, Point end, double startForce, double endForce)
        {
            double pX = start.X + (end.X - start.X) * ((1 - startForce) / (endForce - startForce));
            double pY = start.Y;
            Point p = new Point(pX, pY);
            return p;
        }
    }

    internal enum LineShapes
    {
        Empty = 0,
        //  ○----○
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ○----○

        BottomLeft = 1,
        //  ○----○
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ●----○

        BottomRight = 2,
        //  ○----○
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ○----●

        Bottom = 3,
        //  ○----○
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ●----●

        TopRight = 4,
        //  ○----●
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ○----○

        TopRightBottomLeft = 5,
        //  ○----●
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ●----○

        Right = 6,
        //  ○----●
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ○----●

        AllButTopLeft = 7,
        //  ○----●
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ●----●

        TopLeft = 8,
        //  ●----○
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ○----○

        Left = 9,
        //  ●----○
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ●----○

        TopLeftBottomRight = 10,
        //  ●----○
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ○----●

        AllButTopRight = 11,
        //  ●----○
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ●----●

        Top = 12,
        //  ●----●
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ○----○

        AllButButtomRight = 13,
        //  ●----●
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ●----○

        AllButButtomLeft = 14,
        //  ●----●
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ○----●

        All = 15,
        //  ●----●
        //  |    |
        //  |    |
        //  ●----●
    }
}
```

Also, clean up package.json

**Update**

**If you read the article again, you notice that the value 1 in the interpolation formula is the value of the threshold**

If you check cases with arbitrary threshold but don't modify the interpolation formula (and thus interpolate with threshold set to 1), you may get points that lie outside of the given square!

Updated interpolation routines:

```
private static Point InterpolateVertical(Point start, Point end, double startForce, double endForce, double threshold)
{
   
    double a = ((threshold - startForce) / (endForce - startForce));
    double qX = start.X;
    double qY = start.Y + (end.Y - start.Y) * a;
    Point q = new Point(qX, qY);
    return q;
}


private static Point InterpolateHorizonal(Point start, Point end, double startForce, double endForce, double threshold)
{

    double a = ((threshold - startForce) / (endForce - startForce));
    double pX = start.X + (end.X - start.X) * a;
    double pY = start.Y;
    Point p = new Point(pX, pY);
    return p;
}
```

You correctly noticed that in initial example, you had too dense a grid, and thus running a test for each pixel works just as well.

I checked your sin-cos example, and you are still sampling each point (squares have width and height equal to 1), so there is no real benefit from marching points algorithm.

Check the following initialization code with bigger squares in grid (resolution x resolution)

```
int height = 1000;
int width = height;
int resolution = 20;
double threshold = 0.9;

int xLen = width / resolution;
int yLen = height / resolution;
int[] x = new int[xLen];
int[] y = new int[yLen];
for (int i = 0; i < xLen; i++)
{
    x[i] = i * resolution;
}

for (int j = 0; j < yLen; j++)
{
    y[j] = j * resolution;
}

/////////////////////SIN-COS/////////////////////////////
           
double[,] example = new double[xLen, yLen];
for (int j = 0; j < yLen; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < xLen; i++)
    {
        double example_l = Math.Sin(i * resolution /100.0 ) * Math.Cos(j * resolution /100.0);
        example[j, i] = example_l;
    }
}
```

Play with resolution (for example try resolution = 10) to get smoother shapes.

Comment: Both of your solutions are incorrect. see the updated repository. I removed interpolation entirely. Now, it works perfectly.

Comment: You will realize the issue while trying to load data from the CSV file.

Comment: There is only the me solution, the changes in interpolation are for readibility only. If you remove interpolation, it is no longer marching square algorithm

Comment: the interpolation doesn't work. Probably, the interpolation needs re-checking. I couldn't fix it.

Comment: *If you read the article again, you notice that the value 1 in the interpolation formula is the value of the threshold* --- could u kindly point out where it is written?

Comment: In the image you posted: Since we’re trying to get Q to lie roughly on the counter line where f(x,y)=1, we want f(Qx,Qy)≈1, so let’s substitute that and rearrange.

Comment: Thanks for the discovery (which led to the success of the code) but I think the article didn't make that clear at all.

Comment: Agreed, it's only clear when you know what is going on.

Comment: *when you know what is going on.* --- kindly clarify. what do u mean? How did u realize that 1 is actually the threshold?

Comment: I only meant that although the article is pretty well-written, it takes time until things click in your head. Happy to hear that you arrived at a working solution